# How to evaluate $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } (x \sqrt[n]{ \frac{x+a}{x+b} } -x)=?$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty }\left(x\sqrt[n]{ \frac{x+a}{x+b}}-x\right) = ? $$

please with solution :)

Comment: Rationalize. And the answer follows!

Answer (score 2):

Next time you ask a question on Stack Exchange, you should tell us what you have tried to do about your issue. And yes, you should have tried to do something before asking, because the community isn't here to do your homework for you. But I will answer your question.

You should have mentioned what are $a$ and $b$ and $n$, I will assume that $n$ is an integer with $n \geq 1$, and that $a,b > 0$. I will also assume that $a \neq b$, because if we had $a=b$ then your function would be identically zero.

So, basically, the problem is that as $x \rightarrow \infty$, obviously we know that $\sqrt[n]{ \frac{x+a}{x+b}}$ will approach $1$, so the two terms you are substracting have the same order of magnitude (they are both equivalent to $x$), and cancel out when $x \rightarrow \infty$. The way to sort out such indeterminations is to factor the predominant terms in the sums. For instance, in $x+a$ you should factor by $x$ because $x$ is the predominant term. Same for $x+b$. Here we go:

$$ x\sqrt[n]{ \frac{x+a}{x+b}}-x = x \left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{x+a}{x+b}} -1 \right) = x \left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{x\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)}{x\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)}} -1 \right) = x \left(\left(\frac{1+\frac{a}{x}}{1+\frac{b}{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} -1 \right)$$

What next? The next step is to expand the complicated term as a Taylor series relatively to $\frac{1}{x}$, which obviously approaches $0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Recall that, when $u \rightarrow 0$:
$$ \frac{1}{1+u} = 1-u + o(u)$$

Therefore, when $x \rightarrow \infty$ :

$$ \frac{1+\frac{a}{x}}{1+\frac{b}{x}} = \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{b}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) \right) = 1 +\frac{a-b}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) $$

Recall that, when $u \rightarrow 0$:
$$ (1+u)^{\alpha} = 1+\alpha u + o(u)$$

Applying this with $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}$, we find:

$$ \left(\frac{1+\frac{a}{x}}{1+\frac{b}{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \left(1 +\frac{a-b}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1 +\frac{1}{n}\frac{a-b}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$$

The last step is to substract $1$ and then to multiply by $x$, and you will find:

$$ x\sqrt[n]{ \frac{x+a}{x+b}}-x = \frac{a-b}{n} + o(1) $$

So the limit of the function is $\frac{a-b}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use the generalized binomial expansion to write

$$\left(1+\frac {c}{x}\right)^{\pm 1/n}=1\pm \frac{c}{n\,x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete.  Please advise.  -Mark